# Session variable cannot be passed into query

Tags: php, mysql, ajax, session, post

page1.php has this code

```
<?php
    session_start();

    $_SESSION['supp_id'] = 4;
?>
```

page2.php has this code

```
<?php

session_start();
include "db2.php";

$supp_id = $_SESSION['supp_id'];
var_dump($supp_id);

if(isset($_POST['accept']))
{
    $cust_id = $_POST['cust_id'];
    $cartype = $_POST['cartype'];

    $q=mysqli_query($conn,"INSERT INTO `availablesupp` (`Cust_ID`,`Supp_ID`,`CarType`) VALUES ('$cust_id','$supp_id','$cartype')");
    if($q)
        echo "ok";
    else
        echo "error";

}
?>
```

`$supp_id` did not get passed into the query, and the database is updated with  `Supp_ID = 0;`
However changing `$supp_id = $_SESSION['supp_id']` to `$supp_id = 4` works fine. `var_dump` produced identical results in both cases, `int(4)`.
How do I solve this?

Comment: It should work though, can you add in question what you are getting when printing $_SESSION['supp_id'] and also try printing your query before execution & check the query if its right.

Comment: So `var_dump($_SESSION['supp_id']);` gives you the desired result?

Comment: you could put `"'; DROP availablesup --"` in `$_POST['cust_id']`, wait don't do that. --

Comment: @RyanVincent The variables posted came from buttons, it is still necessary to use that? Sorry I am still new at this.

Comment: @SirajulHaq The query is correct, since replacing $supp_id = $_SESSION['supp_id'] with $supp_id = 4 gets the intended result.

Comment: The issue is that all data in the web-browser can be changed by the user or scripts. Hidden fields, buttons, links etc. You have no control over it. You need to ensure all the input is untrusted and validate it. Sad, but true. There is no certainty that you are communicating with a web-browser. ;-/

Comment: I just installed firebug. I am getting Undefined index: supp_id in ... and NULL for var_dump($_SESSION['supp_id']).